# Path not of legal form error openfiledialog

Tags: c#

I am getting a error when i decrypt my file.
"The path is not of a legal form"

if i direct the privateKeyLocation manually e.g. string privateKeyLocation = @"c:\privatekey.txt", its okay and runs fine.

But i want to find the key file myself using open file dialog.
Anybody know what went wrong?
Thanks in advance!

```
private void decryptFileButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string inputFileLocation = attachmentTextBox.Text;
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

            openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
            openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
            string privateKeyLocation = new FileInfo(openFileDialog1.FileName).ToString();
            string privateKeyPassword = passphrase2TextBox.Text;
            string outputFile = @"c:\Original.txt";

            // decrypt and obtain the original file name
            // of the decrypted file
            string originalFileName =
                        pgp.DecryptFile(inputFileLocation,
                                    privateKeyLocation,
                                    privateKeyPassword,
                                    outputFile);
        }
```

Comment: What is an example of a value of `privateKeyLocation` you get from `FileInfo().ToString()`?  Also, is the Open dialog appearing correctly?  Do you need to call `openFileDialog1.ShowDialog()`?

Answer (score 2):

Just a simple matter of showdialog() and its result:

```
        private void decryptFileButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string inputFileLocation = attachmentTextBox.Text;
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

            openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
            openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string privateKeyLocation = new FileInfo(openFileDialog1.FileName).ToString();
                string privateKeyPassword = passphrase2TextBox.Text;
                string outputFile = @"c:\Original.txt";

                 decrypt and obtain the original file name
                 of the decrypted file
                string originalFileName =
                            pgp.DecryptFile(inputFileLocation,
                                        privateKeyLocation,
                                        privateKeyPassword,
                                        outputFile);
            }
        }
```